# getting directory root isn't acting as expected

Tags: c#

This is probably simple but I'm trying to get the directory root in my code.

Here is my code:

```
var appdir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
var ppsdir = Directory.GetParent(appdir).FullName;

appdir  is coming back as "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PPS\\PpsUpdate\\"
but ppsdir is coming back as "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PPS\\PpsUpdate"
```

I need the ppsdir to be "C:\Program Files (x86)\PPS" so I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: It's the trailing backslash. It's working *exactly* [as documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getparent(v=vs.110).aspx): "The string returned by this method consists of all characters in the path up to, but not including, the last `DirectorySeparatorChar` or `AltDirectorySeparatorChar` ... passing `"C:\Directory\SubDirectory\"` returns `"C:\Directory\SubDirectory`", because the ending directory separator is after `"SubDirectory"`."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one instead:

```
var appdir = Path.GetDirectoryName(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
var ppsdir = Directory.GetParent(appdir).FullName;
```

It should give you the correct dir.

The Path.GetDirectoryName will get the path name up until and not including the last DirectorySeparatorChar. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname(v=vs.110).aspx). The Directory.GetParent gets the parent directory from the string we hand it.

Comment: @CodeCaster Of course. I am a bit tired. I updated the answer with some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

See [Directory.GetParent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getparent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in MSDN:

> The string returned by this method consists of all characters in the path up to, but not including, the last **DirectorySeparatorChar** or **AltDirectorySeparatorChar**.

So in our case `Directory.GetParent` seems just to cut the last `\`.

As @CodeCaster suggested, you may use TrimEnd in order to get rid of trailing `\`s.